# Getting Started with ServiceStack.Text CSV

Tags: csv, servicestack

Hi I have recently gotten started with ServiceStack.

I have been searching the web trying to find a start point with **ServiceStack.Text**. So far, no luck! Could a kind soul please give me an idea on how and where I can get started? All I need is to ***'read' a CSV file*** and get values so I could save into my ***SQL database***.

Do I build a class and override certain methods? Please if anyone could provide a rough structure or sample code that I could easily follow on? I greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you and am sincerely hoping to get started =)

Cheers to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack.Text supports [serializing and deserialising CSV](http://docs.servicestack.net/csv-format).

Most databases have native support for importing data from CSV, here's an example of using [SqlServer Bulk import to import a csv file](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/), you can also [import CSV using powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/28/four-easy-ways-to-import-csv-files-to-sql-server-with-powershell.aspx) or if you prefer to use a GUI you can import it using [SqlServer Management Studio](https://support.discountasp.net/KB/a1179/importing-csv-file-into-your-database-with-sql-server.aspx):

You first need to create a table in your database in which you will be importing the CSV file. After the table is created, follow the steps below:

1. Log into your database using SQL Server Management Studio
2. Right click on your database and select **Tasks** -> **Import Data...**
3. Click the **Next >** button
4. For the Data Source, select **Flat File Source**.  Then use the **Browse** button to select the CSV file.  Spend some time configuring how you want the data to be imported before clicking on the **Next >** button.
5. For the Destination, select the correct database provider (*e.g. for SQL Server 2012, you can use **SQL Server Native Client 11.0***).  Enter the **Server name**; check **Use SQL Server Authentication**, enter the **User name**, **Password**, and **Database** before clicking on the **Next >** button.
6. On the Select Source Tables and Views window, you can **Edit Mappings** before clicking on the **Next >** button.
7. Check **Run immediately** and click on the **Next >** button.
8. Click on the **Finish** button to run the package.

Comment: Hi Mythz,

Thank you very much for your very informative response. Boy, having the wrong idea to start with could spin you off on a totally diff trajectory!

Thanks so much for pointing me in d right direction! You've provided me with several correct options -- I've started looking at the SQL bulk insert =)

Your response is highly appreciated as it saved me a lot of time and effort wondering about the wrong thing.
Highly appreciated! Cheers!